# Android: Focus on TimePicker elements

Tags: android, android-layout, timepicker

How to get focus on time picker elements? I am developing TV app, so it needs to be operated by remote. So I need to apply focus on each element.
TimePicker has 3 elements - hour column, minutes column and AM/PM column.

So how do i get focus on each of these 3 columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get each `NumberPicker` of TimePicker and make whatever you want such as modify, request the focus and so on.

```
NumberPicker hourPicker = (NumberPicker) mTimePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("hour",
     "id", "android"));

NumberPicker minutePicker = (NumberPicker) mTimePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("minute",
     "id", "android"));

NumberPicker amPmPicker = (NumberPicker) mTimePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("amPm",
     "id", "android"));

// this is a number picker modified and there is one for each NumerPicker above
View numberPickerModified = (View) mTimePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input",
     "id", "android"));
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how i can use addfocusables on timerpicker?

Comment: It's better you make different than I said. Please take a look again what I've edited

Comment: the above assumes spinner mode (TimePickerSpinnerDelegate), the names of these views change and they are TextViews in clock mode (TimePickerClockDelegate), check the source

Comment: @HMaclean yeah. Your must edit according to the target you are working on

Answer (score 1):

So the class has since changed and the above did not work for me.

One reason was the view is not a number picker when in clock mode and the second that they have changed the views name.

Here is the Kotlin solution for hours.

```kotlin
 val identifier = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
            "hours",
            "id", "android"
        )
 val hourPicker = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(identifier)
```

The view is a `TextView` and the identifier is 'hours' not 'hour'